# Named Pipes Provider error on classic ASP site in VM environment

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, virtual-machine

I've recently moved a classic ASP site from a single-server IIS6 (Window Server 2003) and SQL Server 2005 setup, to a Hyper-V setup running Windows Server 2012 on the host and two VMs (single machine).

Here is a diagram of the current setup:

[image]

My problem is that I am getting the following error intermittently:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

I've [been told](https://serverfault.com/questions/541429/do-two-vms-on-a-single-hyper-v-host-use-the-nic-when-communicating) and was able to prove that the web-to-DB traffic never uses the physical NIC, so that should rule out any issues w/ the NIC or its drivers/configuration.

I've also made sure that there are no IP conflicts (the host and VM IPs are all different).

The only pattern I can detect is that it seems more likely to happen during peak periods. The odd thing is it can go 7 days without an error, and then on a single day, the error will happen on 50-100 requests, often within the same 30 seconds, or in groups of 30-second intervals.

I've been trying to figure this out for weeks -- since migrating to the new server over 3 weeks ago. If no one here can help, my last resort is to open a ticket with Microsoft. However, I'm not optimistic they will be able to help as I'm not able to reproduce it.

As a last resort, I'm considering moving them back to a single instance, which I'm trying my best to avoid.

**Update:**

Here is the connection string I'm using:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=[my DB VM IP address];Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: instead of using Named Pipes, you may want to modify the connection string to use `network=dbmssocn` - this forces the use of TCP/IP for SQL Server connections.  This might be more reliable.

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Problem is, with this problem going up to a week without happening, it'll be very hard to know when, for sure, it's fixed.

Comment: Amen brother - intermittent problems are tough.